# what's the purpose of enclosing an interface object reference with parenthesis?

Tags: java

I saw this code snippet in the oracle website's java tutorial

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html

```
public Object findSmallest(Object object1, Object object2) {
   Relatable obj1 = (Relatable)object1;
   Relatable obj2 = (Relatable)object2;
   if ((obj1).isLargerThan(obj2) < 0)
      return object1;
   else 
      return object2;
}

public boolean isEqual(Object object1, Object object2) {
   Relatable obj1 = (Relatable)object1;
   Relatable obj2 = (Relatable)object2;
   if ( (obj1).isLargerThan(obj2) == 0)
      return true;
   else 
      return false;
}
```

you see the obj1 inside the if statement is enclosed with parenthesis while the dot is appended to it, how come? what's the purpose of enclosing it with parenthesis? , I thought for as long as an object reference is used with a dot and attach a method name , it's ok already, but how come this code enclosed it with (obj1).methodName ?

Comment: There's no point. The code just isn't very good.

Comment: Yeah nothing really. Feel free to remove it if you feel its just a noise.

Comment: Other dumb things here: why declare argument types of `Object` if they have to be `Relatable`? Why is the comparison method called `isLargerThan` when it's a 3-way comparison instead of a "greater than" test? Why the if-else in `isEqual` instead of `return obj1.isLargerThan(obj2) == 0;`? They should really be using braces for those if-elses, too.

Comment: One of the deleted answers pointed out that it might be an artifact of extracted variables of the explicit cast. It might have originated from `((Relatable)object1).isLargerThan((Relatable)object2)` , despite the smell.

Comment: And the `else` statements are redundant too.

Comment: Why downvote a perfectly legal question? upvoted to compensate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reference is a simple identifier, as in this case, parens are unnecessary, but still perfectly legal.  Thus, writing `(obj1).isLargerThan(obj2)` is exactly the same as writing `obj1.isLargerThan(obj2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing obj1 is braces is not needed, and its not creating any difference.
 Both of the below statements are same and no difference whatsoever.

if ((obj1).isLargerThan(obj2) < 0)

if (obj1.isLargerThan(obj2) < 0)

Thanks